# Stopping OpenLayers Text Icon overlapping on icons

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, style, icon

I created a style with pin SVG and text (ID of my feature) on top, but when I zoom out, the text overlaps other pins as well. Below is the code of style

```
style: function (feature) {
  return [new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon( /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
      anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
      scale: 1,
      src: '/static/images/best-places/place_icon.svg'
    })),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      text: feature.getId().toString(),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#fff'
      }),
    })
  })]
}
```

when I'm zoomed out, it looks good

[image: zoomed out]

when I zoom in, the text overlaps on other features icon

[image: zoomed in]

I'm okay with pins getting overlapped, but I'm expecting text will also get overlapped liked the following example  https://www.trulia.com/for_sale/37.81634,37.83096,-122.28107,-122.26081_xy/16_zm/

Comment: can you check the first line of the question if it should be zoom in?

Comment: possibly disable the labels on smaller zoom levels like it is being done here https://codesandbox.io/s/p4ypj ?

Comment: Usual solution for this kind of problems are clusters, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html

Comment: I want to create behaviour similar to https://www.trulia.com/for_sale/37.81634,37.83096,-122.28107,-122.26081_xy/16_zm/

Comment: I don't want to use the cluster for some pins because those are important, thus I need to show them even though they are overlapping.

Comment: In the cited example icons are also overlapping, so you just want the one with the mouse over to appear on the top? If that is the case, please edit you question and add detailed description of behavior, not only by link. Linked content tends to get lost in time.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: I admit I don't understand what behavior you expect. If it's exactly as in cited example, then please describe it as such. If you can't describe it, add pictures.

Comment: Basically, I want pins overlapping each other (including texts as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function all the features will have the same zIndex, try giving them a unique zIndex:

```
style: function (feature) {
  return [new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon( /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
      anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
      scale: 1,
      src: '/static/images/best-places/place_icon.svg'
    })),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      text: feature.getId().toString(),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#fff'
      }),
    }),
    zIndex: feature.getId()
  })]
}
```

Creating a new style each time the style function is called can lead to poor performance. It would be more efficient to declare a base style

```
var baseStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon( /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
      anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
      scale: 1,
      src: '/static/images/best-places/place_icon.svg'
    })),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#fff'
      }),
    })
  });
```

then simply update it in your style function

```
style: function (feature) {
  baseStyle.getText().setText(feature.getId().toString());
  baseStyle.setZIndex(feature.getId());
  return baseStyle;
}
```